# Info about /rosout topic and rosout node

Tags: ros, rosout

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear Members,

Hi
Hope you guys are having a good one. I am very new to ROS and trying to understand the architecture. Until now I found it very fascinating and the community is doing a great job.
I was looking at different nodes and topics and where I am stuck currently in understanding properly the /rosout topic and rosout node. I have been through the wiki.ros.org but did not understand it completely. That would be great if anyone here can shed some light on it and explain it to me in a more simpler way.

Sincerely,
muscles

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/235370/info-about-/rosout-topic-and-rosout-node/) by [muscles](https://answers.ros.org/users/24958/muscles/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2016-05-27

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Javier V. Gómez](https://answers.ros.org/users/5464/javier-v.-g%C3%B3mez/) on 2016-05-27**:
Hey, welcome! Have you seen this? http://wiki.ros.org/rosout Sorry, I re-read your question. Now I understand you went through that specific page, didn't you?

**Comment by [muscles](https://answers.ros.org/users/24958/muscles/) on 2016-05-27**:
Dear Javier,

Yes I have been through this specific page wiki.ros.org/rosout , but still did not completely understand why do we need rosout and what's the purpose of using it .

Sincerely,

**Comment by [Javier V. Gómez](https://answers.ros.org/users/5464/javier-v.-g%C3%B3mez/) on 2016-05-30**:
Well, I haven't used it at all, but I can imagine an use case: usually you print info on terminal. What if you cannot see this terminal? Then you store it to a file. If you publish to rosout, this is done transparently, and you have timing info, can store it in a rosbag, reproduce it, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The rosout topic allows you to see what's happening in nodes that are running remotely and you potentially don't have access to the console. You can launch the rqt plugin rqt_console http://wiki.ros.org/rqt_console to view outputs.

rqt_logger_level will let you set the logging level remotely as well. : http://wiki.ros.org/rqt_logger_level

Thus you can make all the console outputs available for debugging on any computer connected to the robot. Which is very convenient when you want to connect your robot and debug from a laptop.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2016-12-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-12-23**:
I've always considered `rosout` to be the `stdout` (and `stderr`) of the entire ROS node graph (so that includes all nodes, irrespective of their deployment).